# Firebase realtime database: Is there a way to import json without overwriting existing data?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase realtime database and would like to import some json. However, to import data, Firebase seems to want to delete all existing data in the database. I don't want to do that, I just want to add data by importing it. Is this possible?

;

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible if you write code to read the JSON file and perform the necessary updates against the existing data.  There is no automatic process for this.

Comment: Ah, that's too bad. Thanks though.